# Encog Neural network validation/Testing

Tags: java, validation, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, encog

I have implemented a neural network using encog library as below,

```
MLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(XOR_INPUT, XOR_IDEAL);

    final Propagation  train =  new Backpropagation(network, trainingSet);
    int epoch = 1;
    do {
        train.iteration();
        System.out.println("Epoch #" + epoch + 
                " Error:" + train.getError());
                epoch++;

    } while (train.getError() < 0.009);

    double e = network.calculateError(trainingSet);
    System.out.println("Network trained to error :" + e);
    System.out.println("Saving Network");


    EncogDirectoryPersistence.saveObject(new File(FILENAME), network);
}


public void loadAndEvaluate(){
    System.out.println("Loading Network");
    BasicNetwork network = (BasicNetwork) EncogDirectoryPersistence.loadObject(new File(FILENAME));

    BasicMLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(XOR_INPUT,XOR_IDEAL);

    double e = network.calculateError(trainingSet);

    System.out.println("Loaded network's error is (should be the same as above ):" + e);

}
```

This outputs the error.
But i want to test this with custom data and check if the output given for a set of data is a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are following one of the persistence example. To obtain outputs for some input, use the "compute" function. As an example:

```
    double[] output = new double[1];
    network.compute(new double[]{1.0, 1.0}, output);
    System.out.println("Network output: " + output[0] + " (should be close to 0.0)");
```

[Here's](https://s3.amazonaws.com/heatonresearch-books/free/Encog3Java-User.pdf) the java user guide. It's quite helpful.

Comment: i sued the following data to train and test the neural network but the output is not constant.
public static double train_INPUT[][] = {  {0.0, 0.0},
             {1.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 1.0},
             {1.0, 1.0} 
  };
 public static double tester[] ={1.0, 0.0},;
 public static double train_IDEAL[][] = { {0.0},
            {1.0},
             {1.0},
             {0.0} };

Comment: I'm just noticing that your loop condition is train.getError() < 0.009. Shouldn't that be train.getError() > 0.009 ? I used a 2-3-1 network to test and was able to get down to 0.008 error. (See https://gist.github.com/frankibem/94e588cb2d8ccda2af675f9bde3e25fa and here: https://gist.github.com/frankibem/eeaa066595e6ba791dfc6cea558f92ca